# How to define multi categories posts number

Tags: categories

My args array:

```
$args = array (
    'cat' => '1,3,7',
    'posts_per_page' => '30'
);
```

How to define `posts_per_page`:

- category 1 : 7 posts,
- category 3 : 10 posts,
- category 7 : 13 posts,

Comment: Is this for a secondary query or the main query?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if ther's something similar to `posts_per_category` or `"cat" => array( "5" => array("posts_per_page" => "3")`, but you can do it with conditionals, if you form an array with the posts ids. The problem I can see, is that you have to query all posts or set a limit by date for example, but will go like this.

**Edit**: @Pieter Goosen make me think more about this. He is probably right about the expensiveness of `wp_get_post_categories();` but there's other ways to get the category id, I leave it to you. But giving it a little bit of thought, there's no need to form an array and then call the post later, if you can print whatever you want directly inside the if statements.

```
<?php

$args = array ( 'cat' => '1,2,3', 'posts_per_page' => '-1', );

$query = new WP_Query($args);

$cat_1 = 0;
$cat_2 = 0;
$cat_3 = 0;
if($query->have_posts()) {
    while($query->have_posts()) {
        $query->the_post();
        $post_category = wp_get_post_categories(); //Returns an arry with all the categories ids where the post belogs
        $category_posts = [];  //After edit it is only for knowing which posts have been printed yet        
        //Get all posts ids in a general array and count how many you have inserted from each category
        if (in_array( 1, $post_category) && !in_array($category_posts) $cat_1 <= 8) {
            echo "<div class='post-title'>";
            the_title();
            echo "</div>";
            $category_posts[] = get_the_ID();
            $cat_1++;
        }

        if (in_array( 2, $post_category) && !in_array($category_posts) $cat_2 <= 10) {               echo "<div class='post-title'>";
            the_title();
            echo "</div>";

            $category_posts[] = get_the_ID();
            $cat_2++;
        } 

        if (in_array( 3, $post_category) && !in_array($category_posts) && $cat_3 <= 17 ) {
            echo "<div class='post-title'>";
            the_title();
            echo "</div>";
            $category_posts[] = get_the_ID();
            $cat_3++;
        }

    }
}

//$cat_n is for the number of posts you want from each category
```

**Edited**: (this is not necessary after edit)

Then you'll have to loop trough the `$category_posts` array to get the ids and print whatever you want outside the while loop.

I did this on the fly, so it is probable it has some errors, but this is the general idea.

In this example, if the same posts belogs to two of this categories, it counts for the category with the minor number and not for the other, that's `!in_array($category_posts)` for.

Comment: Although I haven't tested it and although it might work, this is extremely expensive. On very large sites you are going to run into issues. Note, the results from `wp_get_post_categories` are not cached, so you are running an extra db query on **every** post.

Answer (score 1):

There is no native way to achieve this, so you would need to run more than one query to achieve this. If not done correctly, this can become quite expensive, so we need to be smart here.

I thought of a couple ideas here, and this seems to make the mot sense, so here is what we will do

- Run a query for each term to get the amount of posts we want per term. To make this as lean as possible and to really save on db calls and time, we will only get post ID's
- From all these queries, we will build an array of ID's. We need to also remove duplicates in the event that a post belongs to two terms
- Once we have an array of post ID's we will run our final query to get the complete post objects

I have decided to create a function to collect the post ID's and then save everything in a transient which we will flush everytime a new post is created, or when a post is updated, deleted or undeleted. This way, you make your queries even more leaner. At the end of the day, the function only takes 2 db calls in less than 0.005seconds, so it really makes much more sense coming to performance

### THE FUNCTION

Everything in the function is very well commented, so be sure to follow the comments as you go along: (***NOTE:*** All the code in this answer requires a minimum of PHP 5.4)

```
/**
 * Function to get an array of post ID's according to term and according
 * to a specific amount of posts per page set per term
 *
 * @param (string) $post_type
 * @param (string) $taxonomy
 * @param (array)  $args
 * @return (array) $output_ids
 */
function get_unique_ppp_per_category( $post_type = 'post', $taxonomy = 'category', $args = [] )
{
    // Make sure we have a post type and taxonomy and sanitize it
    if (    !$post_type
         || !$taxonomy
    )
        return false;

    if ( $post_type !== 'post' )
        $post_type = filter_var( $post_type, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );

    // Make sure we have a valid taxonomy to avoid bugs
    if (    $taxonomy !== 'category'
         || $taxonomy !== 'post_tag'
    ) {
        // Santitize and validate the taxonomy
        $taxonomy = filter_var( $taxonomy, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );

        // Check if taxonomy exist, if not, return false
        if ( !taxonomy_exists( $taxonomy ) )
            return false;
    }

    // If $args are empty or not an array, return false
    if (    !$args
         || !is_array( $args )
    ) {
        return false;
    }

// Set a transient to store the post ID's. Excellent for performance
    if (    false === ( $output_ids = get_transient ( 'term_id_list_' . md5( $post_type . $taxonomy . json_encode( $args ) ) ) ) ) {
        // Set up a variable to hold an array of post id and id that should not be duplicated
        $post_ids = [];

        /**
         * Loop through the $args array and build our queries
         *
         * We need to make sure that every value, $arg, is an array.
         * That array should have the term id as key and posts per page value
         * as value, so in short, the setup should be '(int) term ID => (int) posts_per_page'
         * If not, we will simply continue. You should however build in some kind of
         * error notice on this as it can and will make debugging easier
         */
        foreach ( $args as $term_id=>$ppp ) {
            // Sanitize and validate our values
            $ppp     = filter_var( $ppp,     FILTER_VALIDATE_INT );
            $term_id = filter_var( $term_id, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT );

            /**
             * Create a flat array of post ID's that we should not duplicate
             *
             * @see array_walk_recursive
             */
            $duplicates = [];
            if ( $post_ids ) {
                array_walk_recursive( $post_ids, function ( $a ) use ( &$duplicates )
                {
                    $duplicates[] = $a;
                });
            }

            // Set up our query args
            $query_args = [
                'fields'         => 'ids', // Get only post ids to make this very quick
                'post_type'      => $post_type,
                'posts_per_page' => $ppp,
                'post__not_in'   => $duplicates, // Do not duplicate these posts
                'tax_query'      => [
                    [
                        'taxonomy'         => $taxonomy,
                        'terms'            => $term_id,
                        'include_children' => false
                    ]
                ],
                // Add any extra parameters here
            ];
            $q = get_posts( $query_args );

            $post_ids[] = $q;
        } // endforeach $args

        /**
         * Flattern the nested array of post ID's
         *
         * @see array_walk_recursive
         */
        $output_ids = [];
        if ( $post_ids ) {
            array_walk_recursive( $post_ids, function ( $a ) use ( &$output_ids )
            {
                $output_ids[] = $a;
            });
        }

        set_transient( 'term_id_list_' . md5(  $post_type . $taxonomy . json_encode( $args ) ), $output_ids, 30*DAY_IN_SECONDS );
    }   

    return $output_ids;
}
```

### USAGE

As per example, you need 7 posts from category 1, 10 posts from category 3, and 13 posts from category 7. The function has three parameters, the first one being post type, the second being taxonomy and the third an array of key/value pairs where the keys are category ID's and the values being the amount of posts for that specific catgory

So, for this example, we will use the build in type `post` and the build in taxonomy `category`

**EXAMPLE**

```
$args = [
    //'category ID' => 'posts_per_page',
    1 => 7,
    3 => 10,
    7 => 13
];
$q = get_unique_ppp_per_category( 'post', 'category', $args );
var_dump( $q );
```

Now we can pass the result from `$q` to a proper `WP_Query`. Just a few notes before we do

- If you need the categories to be in the order as you have passed them to the `get_unique_ppp_per_category` function, you would need to set the `orderby` parameter in your `WP_Query` to `post__in`
- Remember, if you have any post type other than `post`, remember to set the `post_type` parameter as well

Lets get our complete posts now

```
if ( $q ) {
    $query_args = [
        'post__in'       => $q,
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'orderby'        => 'post__in',
        'order'          => 'ASC'
    ];
    $the_query = new WP_Query( $query_args );
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    $the_query->the_post();

        // Your template tags and html markup, like
        the_title();

    } // endwhile
    wp_reset_postdata();
} // endif $q
```

The only thing we are left with is flushing the transient when a new post is published or when a post is deleted, undeleted or updated. We will use the `transition_post_status` hook which will fit the bill

```
add_action( 'transition_post_status', function ()
{
    global $wpdb;
    $wpdb->query( "DELETE FROM $wpdb->options WHERE `option_name` LIKE ('_transient%_term_id_list_%')" );
    $wpdb->query( "DELETE FROM $wpdb->options WHERE `option_name` LIKE ('_transient_timeout%_term_id_list_%')" );
});
```

Comment: It's not Monday yet ;-) Hope the match went well with your Lions team.

Comment: @birgire true, hahaha. Some questions just need and begs for attention, and you enspired me you answer a question after your answer to that other question. As far as the rugby goes, [the Lions won the cup](http://www.sport24.co.za/Rugby/CurrieCup/Lions-crowned-Currie-Cup-champions-20151024), so it was a great weekend ;-)

Comment: Congratulations ;-) It would be nice if `md5()` would accept mixed input. I looked around and found an interesting [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32846231/2078474) on SO regarding `md5()` and arrays. Looks like `json_encode()`, just as you use,  is faster for "short" strings but `serialize()` for "big" strings.

Comment: @birgire great find. Something I will definitely play around with ;-)